# how to open dialog box in input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a normal input

```
          <label className="label-above" htmlFor="Aktenzeichen">Field :</label><br />
          <input id="aktenzeichen"  onKeyDown={(e) => {  setAktenzeichen(e.target.value)}} type="text" /><br />
```

[image]

I want to click on it to pop up a dialog where I can search for data(with autocomplete).

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried to create dialog during onKeyDown,
but the window doesn't pop up.
I tried with </DialogContent> and </Dialog> , but then the dialog is shown immediately when I enter the page, and not when I click

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
METHOD-1

<input id="myInput" placeholder="Enter some text" name="name"/>

const input = document.querySelector('#myInput');

input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  // here you can call your pop-up window
}

METHOD-2

<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="updateValue()">

function updateValue() {
  // here you can call your pop-up window
}
```

Comment: function updateValue() {
    return      <Dialog maxWidth="lg" BackdropProps={{ invisible: true }} onClose={handleClose} 
     aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title">

    <DialogTitle>Behörde-Suche</DialogTitle>
    <DialogContent>
      <TextField
        autoFocus
        onKeyDown={(e) => { setBehoerdeSearchNameWrapper(e) }}
      />
     </DialogContent>
  </Dialog> 
  }

this does not work

Warning: Expected `onInput` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.

Comment: perhaps you meant onInput={updateValue} without brackets?
but this is not working. just doesn't call the function.